# How to declare an "install script" in a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, deployment

I'm new to Node.js and I'm building a little application that connects to a MySQL database.

I wrote a script that initialize the database (well, for now it only creates a table), I invoke it with the command `node storage/init_storage.js` and when the task is done, the script does a `process.exit()` to terminate itself.

It works but I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner way to do that? In the future I will have more tasks to do when I'm reinstalling the app (maybe create folders, run tests...), is there a right place to do those things? Maybe a way to do them when `npm install` is launched?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could have a post-install script, however, you'll find that you end up calling npm install more than once, which would wreck havok on your database if you aren't careful. I would suggest just doing it the way you're already doing it.

Comment: OK, i'll keep doing it that way then, thanks

Comment: That or adding a detection mechanism to it so that it won't run if the storage is already setup. At that point you could just make it part of your app boot process.

Comment: Yes I may do that, but anyway I like to have a "reset everything" button :)